# RxJs Angular Async Validator debounce and take latest value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have async Angular validator to check if account group already exists.

```
public accountGroupAlreadyExistsValidator(orgId: number, parentId: number) {
return (control: AbstractControl) => {
  return new Observable((obs: any) => {
    control
      .valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .filter(value => value.length > 0)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .flatMap(accountGroupName => this.accountGroupService
        .accountGroupExistsInOrganization(orgId, parentId, accountGroupName)
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        result === true ?
          obs.next({ accountGroupAlreadyExists: true }) : obs.next(null);
        obs.complete();
      });
  });
};
```

}

The code works but it sends n number of AJAX requests. How can I modify the code to send only 1 request when user has stopped typing.

Current Scenario: if user types 5 characters, 5 AJAX requests are made.

Comment: You're already using the `debounceTime()` operator. Are you sure the problem is not in the way you're calling the returned function from `accountGroupAlreadyExistsValidator`?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything. Now I have switched from rx operator to simply returning promise object and it is working fine

Comment: Updated code 
`
public accountGroupAlreadyExistsValidator(parentId: number, originalName: string) {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
      clearTimeout(this.validationTimeout);
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.validationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          const accountGroupName = c.value;
          const exists = this.accountGroupService
            .accountGroupExistsInOrganization(parentId, accountGroupName, originalName);
          return exists ? resolve({ accountGroupAlreadyExists: true }) : resolve(null);
        }, 600);
      });
    };
  }
`